# Vue JS NPM Module imported into Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, module

I am trying to import an npm package into my vue.js component. Specifically, I am trying to import ScrollMagic into my project, but I am getting it to be undefined.

I have seen people suggest previously that it should be in my mounted() hook, which I am doing but my import statements (I have tried both in main.js, and in the components  tag but both have returned undefined variables. Any direction would be appreciated.

Script for my component:

```
<script>
import { ScrollMagic } from 'scrollmagic';

export default {
  name: 'Scroller',
  mounted() {
    console.log(ScrollMagic);
  },
};
</script>
```

And in my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
/*
IMPORT STATEMENTS FOR MODULES GO HERE
*/
import sm from 'scrollmagic';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import App from './App.vue';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
/*
Usage statement
*/
Vue.use(sm);
Vue.use(gsap);

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the scrollmagic package doesn't export a variable or function `ScrollMagic`, so it keeps getting undefined?

Have you tried:

```
import * as ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic';
// OR
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic';
```